# journalctl --follow isn't advancing

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, journald

I have a program that continually reads the output of:

`journalctl -o json --follow`

And sends it to another process.  And while it outputs journal entries initially from the tail, new ones don't appear on stdout while it's running.  It's as though follow mode isn't following but stalls.

So to test this, I ran up two terminal windows:

1. `journalctl -o json --follow`
2. `echo "Hello world" | systemd-cat` x 10 times

The first time I ran 2. it appeared to follow.
Subsequent runs of 2 and nothing appears.

This is a huge problem.  Follow isn't really following?

OS is Ubuntu 16.04 on x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Two things might be happening:

1. If you log the same line 10 times, duplicated lines might be filtered, try changing the hello world msg
2. There might be some buffering between the program you use to parse the output of `journalctl -f -o json` and journalctl itself, see [View unbuffered log output from journalctl](https://serverfault.com/questions/832691/view-unbuffered-log-output-from-journalctl)

Comment: I tried both of those things.  Interestingly, that doesn't occur on another machine with a systemd journal.  The journalctl binary is newer.  It might just be a bug.

Comment: upgraded to 18.04, same issue.

Comment: Turned out it was a corrupt /var/log/journal.  Did vaccuum several times to preserve least 10 mins and it was showing events from 6 months ago so.   Blew it all away then voila!

Answer (score 0):

It may also be the case you/someone/ntp changed the time backwards. It turns out that journalctl -f shows the latests logs based on date, not based on latest incoming logs...

Check out: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5345

Answer (score 0):

You may be out of inotify resources. Oddly  My remote VSCode was taking up too many of them. You can increase these by doing something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56292289/1394731

Apparently newer versions of systemd give you warnings when this happens: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2321#issuecomment-1032425855